# Unable to Checkout Angular Tutorial

Tags: git, angularjs

I am trying to follow the AngularJS Tutorial. I have managed to setup all my testing and static webserver ok. However when I get to Step 0 - Bootstrapping the tutorial is asking me to reset my workstation by using the command:

```
git checkout -f step-0
```

when I type this (while I am in the angular-phonecat directory) I get this error message:

```
fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: what happens when you run git status?

Comment: You checked it out with `git clone` right? Not by downloading the zip-file from GitHub?

Comment: that is correct I used git clone to begin with. NSjonas - I get the same error message when I do git status

Comment: Is there a directory named `.git` in your `angular-phonecat` directory?

Comment: no Chris and there does not need to be...according to the tutorial at least

Comment: Did you `cd` into angular-phonecaT?

Comment: yes I did mention that in my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Be sure that you did command

```
git clone git@github.com:angular/angular-seed.git
```

**before**